# Description of H1, H2, S connections on a pulse igniter

Tags: wiring

I would like to replace a piezo igniter in a small project with something that can be electronically controlled (I have created some simple hairspray-powered foam rockets, and I would like to be able to sequence several of them from a computer).

It looks like pulse igniters, [like this](http://amzn.com/B00NM8VIE4), are relatively inexpensive, but it's been hard to find any documentation or wiring diagrams for them and I'm unsure if I understand all the connections.

There are obvious inputs for power and for a switch, but on the high voltage side there are three wires, labelled `HV1`, `HV2`, and `S`.  `HV1` and `HV2` appear to come off either end of a coil, and `S` is a mystery.

The igniter looks something like this:

[image: Diagram of the igniter]

And the innards look actually like this:

[image: Inside of igniter]

`HV1` to `HV2` seems to generate the most effective spark, but I don't know if that's using the igniter correctly or slowly frying its innards. Can someone help explain these labels?

Comment: Don't buy anything without a proper datasheet. The manufacturer should know and should tell you.

Comment: If these are what I think they are, they begin sparking as soon as power is applied

Comment: They have a switch connection which must be closed before they will spark.  The question is primarily about the outputs (HV1, HV2, and S), and what exactly each one is for.

Answer (score 1):

Re the gas igniter drawing - We use these very same igniters in our gas water heaters. The questionmarks in question - connects to a soleniod valve that opens the gasflow when the water valve is opened.

Answer (score 1):

white green black for gas valve (solenoid valve).
 S for flame out sensor.
HV1 and HV2 for sparking pins

Answer (score 1):

HV1=High Voltage 1
HV2=High Voltage 2 - these are the amplified outputs to create the sparks
S=Switch  -  this is the temperature probe so it knows if the flame is on or off